# Run Jetty Website on Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: java, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have created a Java Web Application using Jetty (in Eclipse, using OSGI etc.). The application itself runs quite well (when being tested locally), so I wanted to run it on an Azure virtual machine in order to be accessible for external users (for testing reasons).

What I did so far:

- created an Azure account
- create a virtual machine with Windows Server running in it
- downloaded all my eclipse files etc. to the virtual machine
- started the application (in fact in eclipse, not the compiled jar) in the virtual machine; the application is published to port 8080
- so, when i run a webbrowser in the VM and connect to localhost:8080, everything works well
- but when I try to access the website from external (using my assigned domain of the VM, something.cloudapp.net:8080), it does not work
- I also created endpoints in the azure management console for this VM (80, 8080, etc.)

Does anyone ever tried to run a java webapp on Azure or has a hint what could go wrong here?

Comment: Yes i did that in past and it works. You created the VM in the classic mode or not? May you show the management console screenshot of endpoints?

Comment: Yes please edit your question to show how you set up endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, windows servers in Azure have the windows firewall enabled.  This would block external connections to port 8080 by default.  Try adding an appropriate exception to the windows firewall rules.

Comment: Yes, in fact the firewall blocked. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I think you have correctly configured the new endpoints for the network traffic of Java Webapp. If not or incorrectly does, please refer to the article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal/ to configure again.

Then, as @CtrlDot said, you need to configure the firewall for allowing the inbound traffic on Windows Server.

As reference, please see the article about [allowing inbound traffic to a specified TCP or UDP port on Windows Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754158(v=ws.10).aspx) to do it.